# accessing skeletal tracker data

Tags: openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a problem in accessing and processing of the data given by Kinect in Openni package.
The problem is I am piping the Kinect data to a text file using

rostopic echo /tf >> data.txt

then I am simultaneously trying to access the same data file in another program, but once i run this program the previous command stops writing into the data file. Can anyone please tell how do I make the computer do both the tasks simultaneously?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12968/accessing-skeletal-tracker-data/) by [mehhek](https://answers.ros.org/users/1765/mehhek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds weird what you are trying. Of course it depends on the application but use this as thumb the rule:

- If you want to see or store logging data: using ROS looging features and tools (like rxconsole) are recommended.
- If you want to store structured data for an specific postprocessing or analysis: using [rosbag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag) is recommended.
- If you want to communicate many processes: using the ROS communication mechanisms (topics, services, actions) are recommended.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2012-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0